# How do I get a feed of the 10th page on realbusiness.co.uk?

Tags: url, rss, feed

I'm  trying to pull the 10th page from realbusuiness.co.uk rss feed. I have tried several variations of the url but I can't find the correct one like so:

http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/page10

http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/paged10

http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/?page10

http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/?paged10

http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed?page10

http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed?paged10

Any idea on what the correct url would be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think that there is a 10th page? RSS feeds don't typically provide paging or access to historical data.

Comment: There are other sites that do let me query the 10th page via the RSS feed (financial times, the telegraph)

Comment: They are atypical.

Comment: Ah I see. So it's not possible in this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missing `=` on url. Because the wordpress feed page url is at `http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/?paged=number of page` in your case maybe http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/?paged=10

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Would you know by any chance how to do the same for businesinsider? http://uk.businessinsider.com/rss?paged=

Comment: Ahhh I tried that. It doesn't seem to give you older articles. I'm looking at the pubDate field :/